# The package org.hibernate is accessible from more than one module: hibernate.commons.annotations, hibernate.core

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new in Hibernate.I meet a problem like this: though I configure all the required JARS of Hibernate and MySQL,when I try to import SessionFactory,it 
still shows the wrong information like this:

> The package org.hibernate is accessible from more than one module:
>   hibernate.commons.annotations, hibernate.core

Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is with java 9 with the new introduction to modules.Try changing your execution environment to java 8, if that doesn't work try to Reference your Hibernate jar files in Classpath not Modulepath. Configure it in your project's build path

Answer (score 1):

Reference your Hibernate jar files in Classpath not Modulepath. Configure it in your project's build path.it will work